# C# Chart, x - axis with 12 month intervals when data only has example : 3 months

Tags: c#, sql, database, charts, axis

I am making a chart with C# where the user selects a start date and end date.  I would like the x - axis to show each month as an interval and label (Jan, Feb, Mar, etc..) even if there is no data retrieved for that month.  This would mean some months are blank.  If there an easy way to do this?

```
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    string[] months = new string[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };

    for (int i = 0; i < months.Length; i++)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {                                       
            if (Convert.ToDateTime(reader["dateValue"]).ToString("MMM") != months[i].ToString())

            {
                this.chartCasesByDate.Series["Number of Cases"].Points.AddXY(months[i].ToString(), "");
                break;

            }
            else
            {
                this.chartCasesByDate.Series["Number of Cases"].Points.AddXY(Convert.ToDateTime(reader["dateValue"]).ToString("MMM"), reader["count"]);                            
            }
        }                                                                                                
    }
```

Comment: If you can include what you have already tried and any errors you got that could help people to make suggestions

Comment: This is best done by __not adding the x-valaues as strings. Correct this mistake__ and you can set the x-axis `Interval` and `IntervalType` as needed. While you add strings all x-values are __zero__ (!!) and no useful settings are possible. __Common error..__ -  When you add `DateTimes` you can set the `LabelFormat` etc as you want, incl. `"MMM"`..